# Django REST Framework serializers: readable and kinda writable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

These Django REST Framework serializers sure can be puzzling.

I have a situation which I already resolved, but was left wondering if the solution I pulled off really is the smoothest one.

I have some product information in my database. As usual, a product is referred to with a product ID. I of course want product IDs to be readable, so I implement a ModelSerializer that has

```
read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

These IDs and other product information is then passed as JSON to the frontend. What I don't want to happen is that unknown people on the internet are able to send me arbitrary product IDs and other information and put these into my database, so that's why I make the field a read_only_field.

However, I do want to be able to receive valid, existing product data from the frontend and deserialize it to a Python object. Because the ID field is a read_only_field, DRF ignores it and the ID never gets deserialized. So I guess I kinda want these serializers to be writable, too. Just not... too writable.

What I did now is I kinda made an intermediary ProductSerializer that's both readable and writable and that'll never get saved to the database directly.

Or should I keep the original ModelSerializer readable and writable but overwrite .is_valid() to check that we're handling an existing product ID?

Or is there some other way to go about this dilemma?

edit0:

So what I wanna accomplish, is something like these steps:

1. Receive an image upload via dropzone.js
2. Analyze the image, make sure it's a proper one and if it is, send back a JSON response with product recommendations array based on image properties. At this point, product data should be serialized from the DB.
3. User selects quantities and whatnot and then sends this product information back. Here I use a PUT to an endpoint currently called '/basket'.
4. Deserialize this information back to product objects and build a shopping cart of sorts. This is where I noticed the problem. A malicious user could send arbitrary information, so I want to make sure such bogus is not accepted and only products that really are in the DB are also handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, this is a bit different problem. The only thing you should care is making sure all write-request require authorization. No one should be allowed to put anything to your DB, but for those having proper permissions. While those having them are considered as trusted users and you should not be concerned that they can post something bad to your DB.

DRF includes token authentication, session authentication and other [auth methods](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) that you can use in connection with [Permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/). You **must** make all POST, PUT and DELETE request protected by permissions system, otherwise your API is extremely vulnerable.

And if I recall it correctly, primary key on a ModelSerializer is read-only by default.

Comment: If you allow posting images from unauthed users without moderation and limits you are at the risk of ending up by getting flushed with fake images submitted by bots which will occupy the whole your storage space. **All** write requests should be permissions protected.
Even more, if you merely need to upload images, this has nothing to do with exposing products table for writing at all. You can expose images upload endpoint API and associate each image with the product on the backend. Your unauthorized users should never POST and PUT to the products endpoint.

Comment: Sorry about the deleted reply. It got out of hand and I later noticed I'll never be able to explain myself with the character limit on the comment. See edit0 in the original question instead.

Comment: Sorry, but what you are trying to explain is a mystery to me. After three your comments I understand neither what you are trying to do nor what data you save, nor why, in your oppinion, "handling" DB-existing products data that comes from anonymous user is safer than doing so with non-existing products. Both of it is equally insecure. You should not allow writing to your DB by anonymous users, that is all you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sound advice. While we've drifted far from the original topic, it's still been very good information!

I'm just left wondering: don't, for example, a lot of e-commerce sites basically take data from unknown users into their DB when registering users' orders and customer information? Not every store forces a log-in and, say, an e-mail verification prior to ordering. And, for example, I'll need to receive those image uploads via POST requests before I have a chance of authenticating the user. Kinda like what imgur.com does.

 Yeah, properly off-topic.

Comment: Guess I'll need to look into this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

Comment: A few proxy servers can make throttling useless, if someone really wants to flush your DB with fake data. I think, we are not so far from the topic, as, it seems to me, that your problem is not making 'id' writable/non-writable, but rather entire underestimation of the consequences of allowing anonymous users to write to your DB.

Most e-commerce platforms validate at least something prior to commit an order: email, Facebook or Google account or phone number. If you don't do anything of this, one day you can see hundreds of fake orders per minute in your admin area.

Comment: And after all, you may receive any data via POST or PUT, but you should not write it anywhere, if you don't trust the source.

Comment: This has been a very valuable conversation indeed. Some of these things I of course knew and will consider all of your advice. Thank you! I'll mark your answer as accepted. While it might've not been head-on to the original issue, it has made me rethink my approach in a way that'll likely ultimately lead to a dissolution of the original issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138127/discussion-between-xtrom0rt-and-abcdn).

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', ...)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: This is the exact solution that gave me a throbbin' head ache